# ActivityManager: [1] Segmentation fault am start -n com

Tags: android

i seem to be getting this error everytime i try to run my android app on a emulator:

> ActivityManager: [1]   Segmentation
>   fault      am start -n com

any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one thing that works great with the emulator is deleting the AVD (android virtual device) and creating a new one!